# Typescript shared path, unable to export const

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm working on a project where the front-end and the back-end reside in the same directory and both use `TypeScript`.

I am using a shared path to store some interfaces and constants between the two projects.

But, when I try to export a constant from any file in `/shared`, I get a :

`Error: Cannot find module '@shared/test'`

#### server-config.ts:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./src/server/",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "target": "ES2017",
  "types": ["node"],
  "outDir": "./dist/",
  "allowJs": true,
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "@shared/*": ["../shared/*"]
  },
```

#### /shared/test.ts:

```
// If I remove the following line, no compile error, even finds TheTest
export const TEST = 'test'; 

export class TheTest {

}
```

#### import

```
// << Module not found (only if I import TEST)
import { TEST, TheTest } from '@shared/test';

export function Foo() {
  console.log(TEST);
}
```

Comment: So if you leave `TEST` in `/shared/test.ts` but only import `TheTest` is it still problematic?

Comment: Importing from `@shared/test` works fine, BUT if it is a `const` that I import, I get `module not found @shared/test`

Comment: ok, so just an observation, but is the const actually named `TEST`? If you rename it to something else and import does it work?

Comment: It does not. Original name wasnt TEST, I made it simple for the post.

Comment: Ok, so finally does it work with `import * from '@shared/test'`?

Comment: If I do `import * as t from '@shared/sockets/test';` it compiles.
If then i do `t.TEST` it crashes

Comment: With a particular error? If you import as suggested and just reference `TEST` does that work? I'm just trying to rule things out here but it seems relatively buggy, are you on the latest version?

Comment: I get exactly the same error. And I added a `as` because it won't let me import otherwise. Yes latest version.

Comment: I wish I could make a plunkr or something, but with double tsconfigs in my case its impossible

Comment: This has to be caused because of the `paths` `@shared` because for now I export those constants from another directory that isn't in `shared` and it works...

Comment: wonder if it could be with the fact the folder isn't in the same directory (not that it should matter). But could you try a relative path that's in the same CWD e.g. `./src/shared`